# getting a combo box that has a row source equal to a query - and the query takes data from a form - to update

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a combo box with a row source based on an SQL query about like

```
SELECT DISTINCT Database_New.ASEC 
FROM Database_New 
WHERE Database_New.Date>= DateSerial([cboYear], 1, 1)  
      And Database_New.Date<= DateSerial([cboYear], 12, 31);
```

the trouble is that if I change the value of cboYear, the values in the drop down cboASEC do not update. I have to open the query, save it and close it to get the thing to update while I have the form open. Is there a way to get the cboASEC to update somehow? maybe a little tidbit of code in the cboYear - afterupdate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
 Me.cboASEC.Requery
```